# Unit or Acceptance test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, acceptance-testing

Imagine I have the following class structures:

```
public interface Sender {
   void send(String note);
} 

public interface Agent {
   void sendNote(String note);
}

public class Emailer implements Sender {
    void send(String note) {
       //...do something
    }
}

public class Helper {
    List<String> populateNotes() {
        //...do something
    }
}

public class EmailAgent implements Agent {
   List<String> notes;

   void sendNote(String note) {
      Helper helper = new Helper();
      notes = helper.populateNotes();
      for (String s : notes) {
           Sender sender = new Emailer();
           sender.send(s);
      }

   }
}
```

Now, I want to unit test the `sendNote()` method in EmailAgent. However, there is a dependency on `Helper` as it needs to populate the list `notes`. If in the JUnit test I first call `populateNotes()` before calling `sendNote()`...

1. Is this a unit test or acceptance test?
2. Or should I hard coded the list?

Comment: You should look into a mocking framework.  With [JMockit](http://jmockit.org), you'd set up a mock `Helper` that will return a hard-coded list of strings when you call `populateNotes`, and a mock `Emailer` along with `Verifications` that the `send` method of your emailer is getting the strings you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Or use suggestion 2 - create a stub producing a hard-coded list - then unit test the sendNote method. Mocking would also help with this but requires coding against interfaces to be of any use. While it will work, a simple stub should also do the trick.